# Alternative redirect in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a ASP.NET Web Forms application. In this application, on one of the forms I upload a file then redirect to a certain page:

```
            string UrlToRedirect = "";

            if (formKey != null)
                UrlToRedirect = httpRequest.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?id=" + formKey.FormKey1.ToString();
            else
                UrlToRedirect = httpRequest.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?state=" + result;

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(UrlToRedirect);
            return response;
```

For unknown reasons (I've never been able to reproduce it) I sometimes get an error on production.

Since I'm unable to reproduce it I'm somewhat in a bind... I have to fix it, but I don't really know what's going wrong.

So I was wondering, is there another way to obtain a redirect?

Comment: What error do you get on production?

Answer (score 0):

I may know what's causing your error as I was chasing a similar issue for some time.  Accessing `httpRequest.UrlReferrer` can throw if the header contains a malformed referring url which can sometimes happen.  So you need to wrap any that code in a try catch block.